# Bulk copy from SQL Server CE to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, sqlbulkcopy

There is `SqlCeBulkCopy` library (for Windows CE) that allows to fast copying from SQL Server database to SQL Server CE on mobile devices?

Is there some Windows CE library that allows to do it backward? I mean copy from SQL Server CE on mobile device to SQL Server?

Comment: Merge Replication or Remote Data Access!

Comment: If I understand correctly Merge Replication and Remote Data Access are web services? So I cannot use it, I refer to the database directly. I need direct database solution.

Comment: You may be able to connect using System.DataSqlClient on the device, but that client does not have the SqlBulkCopy API